# Nuxt Prerender does not match with Thymeleaf

Tags: vue.js, thymeleaf, nuxt.js

I have a weird issue. This is the context. Our team is in charged of SEO pages of the company. We had these pages with angularjs. This framework is not SEO friendly at all so we recently decided to migrate to vuejs with Nuxt. For the moment, we don’t have available SSR so we make prerender. We use java for the backend and we also use thymeleaf in order to communicate front and back.

The problem is, that we include the thymeleaf tags in our code ( for instance

```
<p th:text=${‘test’}>
```

And when we prerender the page ( create dist folder ) this tag remains in the html ( as expected ). We use JBOSS to serve the page and now we have the next problem: When the page is render, thymeleaf replace the var and we can see the code replaced if we open ‘view source’ (
test

).
Nevertheless, what client sees is the code with the thymeleaf variables (

```
<p th:text=${‘test’}>
```

). I guess, the problem is related with the Virtual DOM. webpack creates a bundle which associates the dom with the text.
Is there any way in nuxt to avoid create a virtual DOM and let thymeleaf keep theis substitutions ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The Thymeleaf in the question is not valid Thymeleaf: `<p th:text=${‘test’}>`. This is valid: `<p th:text=${'test'}>`. The difference is the use of standard keyboard apostrophes (`'`) vs. so-called curly or smart apostrophes (`‘’`). Which ones are you using in your Thymeleaf template?

Comment: Thanks Andrew. The snippet is only an example. Probably I probably typed the wrong quote, my fault. But the main problem is how nuxt is dealing the virtual DOM. The thyme leaf is working well. ( This is my  assumption, but I'm not sure ). Thanks again